# Query works as expected direct in MySQL or using mysqli in PHP, but not in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I do following selects direct in MySQL or using mysqli in PHP and they work just as expected:

MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `publn_data` WHERE publn_auth = 'EP' AND publn_nr = 2007
SELECT * FROM `publn_data` WHERE publn_auth = 'EP' AND publn_nr = 0002007
```

and both give me the expected result:

```
id | publn_auth | publn_nr | author  |
09 | EP         | 0002007  | J.Ferri |
```

And here the query in PHP:

```
$query = "
    SELECT id, publn_auth, publn_nr, author
    FROM publn_data
    WHERE publn_auth = '$publnAuth'
    AND publn_nr = $publnNr";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'].', '.$row['publn_auth'].', '.$row['publn_nr'].', '.$row['author'];
}
```

This is printed on the screen: 09, EP, 0002007, J.Ferri. No problem if variable $publnNr = 2007 or 0002007.

But when I use PDO it only works when I write the full $publnNr = 0002007. When I write only 2007 I receive no result (and no error).

Here the code using PDO:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT id, publn_auth, publn_nr, author
    FROM publn_data
    WHERE publn_auth = :auth AND
          publn_nr = :nr';

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':auth' => $publnAuth,
                      ':nr' => $publnNr));

    while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $r['id'].', '.$r['publn_auth'].', '.$r['publn_nr'].', '.$r['author'];
    }
```

I would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

=== EDIT ===

Here some extra details asked in the comments  from fred-ii-

I get $publnAuth and $publnNr from a form that sends $_POST['publn-in'].
In the field the user usually write EP0002007 or EP2007.
In the end I do the following (there's some work around, but I think it's not essencial here):

```
$publnIn = $_POST['publn-in'];
$publnAuth = substr("$publnIn", 0, 2);
$publnNr = substr("$publnIn", 2);
```

It give us $publnAuth = EP and $publnNr = 0002007 or 2007 accordingly to what the user has inserted.

Moreover we have in the columns of the table publn_auth: EP and publn_nr: 0002007.

publn_auth char(2) and
publn_nr varchar(15).

== EDIT II ==

Based on Sebas' comments:
This is the info we have after a "describe publn_data":

```
Field       Type        Null        Key     Default     Extra
id          int(10)     YES         MUL     NULL
publn_auth  char(2)     YES         MUL     NULL
publn_nr    varchar(15) YES         MUL     NULL
author      varchar(64) YES         MUL     NULL
```

Comment: `and both give me the expected result` I don't flicking believe you, or at least not *that* result. And for my next magic trick, I will need a `describe publn_data` please.

Comment: Hello @fred-ii- thanks for your comments. I put some extra information above in the questions and correct the alpha issue. You're right: It should be EP.

Comment: Hello @Sebas, what do you mean with "need a describe publn_data"? Do you mean a description? Sorry, I'm not fluent in English.

Comment: Please run the command `describe publn_data;` in mysql and give us the result.

Comment: Hello @Sebas, thanks for your help. I've just edited the question with the results of describe publn_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MYSQL query and in your PHP code you give MYSQL an integer value instead of an string to compare against publn_nr (which is a varchar). I assume MYSQL implicitly cast publ_nr to an integer then and (int) 2007 == (int) 0002007.

When you use PDO you give it a string and then in compares two strings and '2007' != '0002007'.

3 possible solutions (you can pick one):

1. change the column publ_nr to integer (if that is possible, it won't store the leading 0 anymore)
2. make sure the value you are looking for is a string incl. the leading 0s
3. cast publ_nr to integer in your PDO-statement

Comment: Dear @thorsten, thanks for your answer! To me only option 3 would be possible. But could you please tell me how can I cast publn_nr to integer in the PDO-statment?

Comment: something like this: WHERE CAST(publ_nr AS UNSIGNED) = :nr

Comment: Just be aware that this column can hold strings. So 'XYZ' is a perfectly fine publ_nr according to the DB. If you cast that to int you get a 0.